Setting proper CSP for MVC application
I have an old MVC5 application, that I needed to add CSP header. After adding one I had errors in my browser that application uses inline-scripts, searched for solution and decided to use 'nonce'.
Finally added CSP like so:
script-src 'self' 'nonce-{0}'
only to find out that I still have messages from external libraries used by application:
controls?v=447BY4awmUbik-qtaXBkwn89uKSmh14ZfB56yFkLtrE1:475  Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-SVhCK+Qb6qZDRLWrpV8wViB4G52gniO8y3TQbjfuHKY='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.
when I check the network tab the nonce- for loaded lib is different:

is that what causes the problem or should I address it differently?
Is there anyway to fix that without unsafe-?
I added CSP header with nonce which solved the problem for all application (excluding external libraries)

How did you add that CSP header? By using OWIN middleware, something like this? In addition, have you deployed your application on IIS? Or are you trying to achieve this requirement through IIS configuration?

Something very similar to this, except that I don't have OWIN configured here so I alter HttpApplicationState, example: HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("Nonce", nonce);. And then in IHtmlString extension method I call helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Application.Get("Nonce"); instead of helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext();. I run application on the IIS and CSP header is configured with Application_PreSendRequestHeaders event (not via IIS configuration).

Does it match the corresponding external library in the page source code? I think the problem might be that the nonce is generated multiple times in different parts of the request's lifecycle. As far as I know, the correct usage should be to use a separate nonce for each HTTP response. In addition, does the problem only occur in IIS sites?
